# How to use form.as_table and crispy forms together?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I want to use form.as_table and crispy forms together, but it is generating an error as shown in the screenshot below :- [image]

Here is my code :-

```
<form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{form.as_table|crispy}}<br>
    </table>
    <input class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" value="Create" id="create">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check [documentation](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_formsets.html#custom-templates-and-table-inline-formsets) which can be helpful.

> The name of the template to use is table_inline_formset.html and you
> use it doing:
>
> helper.template = 'bootstrap/table_inline_formset.html'